# Continuity in different metrics:

Tags: continuity, metric-spaces, supremum-and-infimum

> Let $X = C([0,1];\mathbb{R} )$ be space of continuous real valued fns defined on [0,1] equipped with sup metric $d$ given by : $$d(f,g) = sup_{x \in [0,1]} |f(x) - g(x) |$$

> Consider map $I: X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined by $$I(f) = 1 + \frac{1}{2} \int_{0}^{1} f(x) dx \ \ \ \forall f \in X$$

> Prove map $I$ defined FROM sup metric onto $\mathbb{R}$ with usual metric is $\textbf{continuous}$

The way i started was through the definition, so here choose a, continuous at $a$ if given any $\epsilon  \ \exists \delta>0 \ s.t. $ $$d_y(I(f) , I(a) ) < \epsilon \ \text{whenever}\  \ d_x(x,a) < \delta$$

So just putting these in we just get $$\left |1 + \frac{1}{2} \int_0^1 f(x)dx - (1 +  \frac{1}{2} \int_0^1 f(a)dx\right| < \epsilon$$
Simplifying this, $$\left |\frac{1}{2} \int_0^1 f(x) - f(a)dx\right| \ < \ \epsilon \ \text{whenever} \ d_x(x,a) < \epsilon$$

But here, $$d_x(x,a) = sup_{x \in [0,1]} |x - a |, \ \ \ \text{I think. This is where I'm confused}$$

Simplifying further, we get $$\frac{1}{2} \int_0^1 |f(x)-f(a)| dx < \epsilon$$ whenever the above holds.

Now the part where my question comes in - how do I complete this fully? Is it just choose $$\delta \leq 2\epsilon$$ and the above will all hold, or is that too vague or wrong?

If someone could help that would be really helpful thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are supposed to prove is that, if $f\in C([0,1];\Bbb R)$ and $\varepsilon>0$, then there is some $\delta>0$ such that $d(g,f)<\delta\implies\bigl|I(g)-I(f)\bigr|<\varepsilon$. Just take $\delta=\frac\varepsilon2$. Then, if $d(g,f)<\delta$ (that is, if $\sup_{x\in[0,1]}\bigl|g(x)-f(x)\bigr|<\delta$), you have\begin{align}\bigl|I(g)-I(f)\bigr|&=\left|\left(1+\frac12\int_0^1g(x)\,\mathrm dx\right)-\left(1+\frac12\int_0^1f(x)\,\mathrm dx\right)\right|\\&\leqslant\frac12\int_0^1\bigl|g(x)-f(x)\bigr|\,\mathrm dx\\&<\frac12\int_0^1\delta\,\mathrm dx\\&=\frac\delta2\\&=\varepsilon.\end{align}

Comment: Amazing! Thank you

Comment: I'm glad I could help.